# Avoiding repetition in XSL templates

Tags: xml, xslt, dry

I've been playing around with XML + XSL as a tool for generating HTML emails. Since email code relies so heavily on outdated markup and inline styles, I thought it would be nice to extract the actual content from all the craziness required to format it.

But as I'm going further, and making more templates, I find I am repeating myself more and more. Is there a way to dry out XSL stylesheets, or will I have to clog up my XML files with presentational elements? Let's take this chunk of XML as an example:

```
<root>
  <headline>Hello</headline>
  <button>Click me</button>
</root>
```

Both the headline and the button need some html around them (like an `H1` and a `div`), but since we're talking about email, they also need a table cell, a table row, and a table, like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Hello</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So the naïve solution is to include that table markup in each element's stylesheet, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="headline">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

But say that during testing, I find there's a bug in Outlook 2007 which means all of these wrapper tables need an additional attribute: `cell-padding=0;`. If I've hardcoded the table markup, I may have to go to dozens of templates to propagate that fix.

Is there a way to create a "partial" template of the wrapper table, and reference these in the individual templates for the headline and the button?

I know I could just change the markup to look like this:

```
<root>
  <table>
    <headline>Hello</headline>
  </table>
  <table>
    <button>Click me</button>
  </table>
</root>
```

But that feels like kicking the can down the road. What if I find out that, due to a bug in Gmail's mobile app, all the `td`s need a special style declaration of their own? Then the solution would be to go in and change the markup so that it was indistinguishable from the final output, at which point, what are the XSL templates really doing?

I tried a solution with `call-template`, but didn't get anywhere. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Which version of XSLT does your processor support?

Comment: My processor supports XSLT 1.0, but I think Saxon has an open-source processor that could get me to 2.0.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, you could take advantage of the `xsl:next-match` instruction. In XST 1.0, you can do something similar by applying templates to the current node using `mode`.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can merge your `table` templates like this

```
<xsl:template match="headline|button">
    <table cell-padding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::headline]">
    <h1>
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </h1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::button]">
    <div>
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

This would combine your two example templates into one and split it again later into two different paths. I also added your *Outlook 2007* handling.

The output of the above templates is

```
<table cell-padding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cell-padding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Click me</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm concerned about how such a solution tolerates changing requirements/the scale I'm at (twenty components and counting). Say that the button element has to be wrapped in a div, and not an h1. Is there a way to handle that without duplicating this template, or introducing some if/else statements? Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: I updated my answer to better handle this situation.

Comment: @ErikG Please add that requirement to your question.